# Object Arraylist fails to store objects

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, methods

I am new to Java and I am trying to create a library program containing two separate class files. One file contains the Book class while the other contains the Library class.

Book class:

```
public class Book { 
    private boolean borrowed;
    private static String title; 

    // Creates a new Book 
    public Book(String title) { // Implement this method  
    // Marks the book as rented 
        Book.title = title;
        borrowed = false;
    }
    public void borrowed() { // Implement this method } 
    // Marks the book as not rented
        borrowed = true;
    }
    public void returned() { // Implement this method } 
        borrowed = false;
    }
    public boolean isBorrowed() {
        return borrowed; // Implement this method } 
    // Returns the title of the book public 
    }
    public static String getTitle() { // Implement this method
        return title;
    }
}
```

Library class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import package.Book;

public class Library {
    private String hours;
    private String address;
    private String title;
    private Book book;
    private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();


    // Add the missing implementation (methods and data definitions) to this class 
    // Constructor – look it up
    public Library(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        hours = "9 am to 5 pm";
        }
    void printOpeningHours() 
    {
        System.out.println(hours);
    }
    void printAddress() {
        System.out.println(address);
    }
    void addBook(Book book) 
    {
            this.book = book;
            books.add(book);
    }
    void printAvailableBooks() {
        if (books.size() == 0){
            System.out.println("There are no books available");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(books);
        }
    }
    void borrowBook(String title)
    { 
        this.title = title;
            for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
                if ((books.get(i).getTitle()) == title) {
                    if (book.isBorrowed() == false){
                        book.borrowed();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, that book is already checked out");
                    }
                        
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, no such book is available");
                }
            }
    }

    
    
    void returnBook(String title) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
            if (book.getTitle() == title) {
                if (book.isBorrowed() == true){
                    book.returned();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create two libraries 
        Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St."); 
        Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St."); 

        // Add four books to the first library 
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code")); firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Le Petit Prince")); 
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Tale of Two Cities")); firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings")); 

        // Print opening hours and the addresses 
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        firstLibrary.printOpeningHours(); 
        System.out.println("Library addresses:"); 
        firstLibrary.printAddress(); 
        System.out.println(); 
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        secondLibrary.printOpeningHours(); 
        System.out.println("Library addresses:"); 
        secondLibrary.printAddress(); 

        // Try to borrow The Lords of the Rings from both libraries System.out.println("Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:"); firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings"); 
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings"); secondLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings"); 
        System.out.println(); 

        // Print the titles of all available books from both libraries System.out.println("Books available in the first library:"); firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks(); 
        System.out.println(); 
        System.out.println("Books available in the second library:"); secondLibrary.printAvailableBooks(); 
        System.out.println(); 

        // Return The Lords of the Rings to the first library 
        System.out.println("Returning The Lord of the Rings:"); firstLibrary.returnBook("The Lord of the Rings"); 
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

However, my issue is that when I try to add a book in the books array via the addBook(book) method, it doesn't do so, and as a result, it prints out "Sorry, that book is already checked out."

Here is the result for clarification:

```
Library hours:
9 am to 5 pm
Library addresses:
10 Main St.

Library hours:
9 am to 5 pm
Library addresses:
228 Liberty St.
Sorry, that book is already checked out
Sorry, that book is already checked out
Sorry, that book is already checked out


Books available in the second library:
There are no books available

Returning The Lord of the Rings:
```

What should I do so that the arraylist will recognize the book objects implemented?

Comment: *private static String title * why it is static?

Comment: Use "equas" method to compare strings

Comment: While I believe it fixed the borrowBook method, I still need the addBook method so that it allows book objects to be stored in the array list Books.

Comment: @yungstirjoey666 how about you follow the given answers instead of the comments. Your `addBook` is fine, it is just that your `borrowBook` is sooo broken that I doubt you fixed it unless you pasted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your `borrowBook` method is all over the place.

It should be something along the lines of

```
void borrowBook(String title) { 
    for (Book book : books) {
        if (book.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            if (!book.isBorrowed()) {
                book.borrowed();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that book is already checked out");
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sorry, no such book is available");
}
```

That

- removes the `title` assignment
- simplifies the boolean logic
- properly compares strings
- properly returns early
- only prints the error message at the very end
- removes usage of the `book` field (which combined with the `title` screwed everything up)
- utilizes a for-each instead of a regular for
- **don't make the `Book`'s `title` or `getTitle` `static`**.

Additionally **remove the `title` and `book` fields from the `Library` entirely**, they should not be there ever.

And then finally note that the second library really has no books added to it.

You should implement the `returnBook` in a similar fashion, it has a similar string comparison flaw.

Answer (score 1):

The check

```
if ((books.get(i).getTitle()) == title) {
```

Is an equally by reference, which  always evaluated to *false * in your case. Change it as:

```
 if ((books.get(i).getTitle()).equals(title)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited some part of your code. I split into two seperate file your Library.java. The first is Library.java, second is Application.java.

Your Book.java:

```
public class Book { 
    private boolean borrowed;
    private String title; 

    // Creates a new Book 
    public Book(String title) { // Implement this method  
    // Marks the book as rented 
        this.title = title;
        this.borrowed = false;
    }
    public void borrowed() { // Implement this method } 
    // Marks the book as not rented
        this.borrowed = true;
    }
    public void returned() { // Implement this method } 
        this.borrowed = false;
    }
    public boolean isBorrowed() {
        // Returns the title of the book public 
        return this.borrowed; // Implement this method } 
    }
    public String getTitle() { // Implement this method
        return this.title;
    }    
   
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "title: " + this.title + ", borrowed: " + this.borrowed;
    }
}
```

Your Library.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {
    private String hours;
    private String address;
    private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    // Add the missing implementation (methods and data definitions) to this class
    // Constructor – look it up
    public Library(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        hours = "9 am to 5 pm";
    }

    void printOpeningHours() {
        System.out.println(hours);
    }

    void printAddress() {
        System.out.println(address);
    }

    void addBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
        System.out.println("Added book " + book.getTitle());
    }

    void printAvailableBooks() {
        if (books.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("There are no books available");
        } else {
            System.out.println(books);
        }
    }

    void borrowBook(String title) {
        System.out.println("Borrowing the " + title);
        int foundIndex = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
            if (books.get(i).getTitle().equals(title)) {
                foundIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundIndex >= 0) {
            if (!books.get(foundIndex).isBorrowed()) {
                books.get(foundIndex).borrowed();
                System.out.println("Book borrowed.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that book is already checked out");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, no such book is available!");
        }

    }

    void returnBook(String title) {
        int foundIndex = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Returning the book " + title);
        for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
            if (books.get(i).getTitle().equals(title)) {
                foundIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if (foundIndex >= 0) {
            if (books.get(foundIndex).isBorrowed()) {
                books.get(foundIndex).returned();
                System.out.println("Book returned.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Book didn't borrowed.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, no such book is available!");
        }
    }
}
```

Application.java:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create two libraries 
        Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St."); 
        Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St."); 

        // Add four books to the first library 
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code")); 
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Le Petit Prince")); 
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Tale of Two Cities")); 
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings")); 

        // Print opening hours and the addresses 
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        firstLibrary.printOpeningHours(); 
        System.out.println("Library addresses:"); 
        firstLibrary.printAddress(); 
        System.out.println(); 
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        secondLibrary.printOpeningHours(); 
        System.out.println("Library addresses:"); 
        secondLibrary.printAddress(); 

        // Try to borrow The Lords of the Rings from both libraries System.out.println("Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:"); firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings"); 
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings"); 
        secondLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings"); 
        System.out.println(); 

        // Print the titles of all available books from both libraries System.out.println("Books available in the first library:"); firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks(); 
        System.out.println(); 
        System.out.println("Books available in the second library:"); 
        secondLibrary.printAvailableBooks(); 
        System.out.println(); 

        // Return The Lords of the Rings to the first library 
        // System.out.println("Returning The Lord of the Rings:"); 
        firstLibrary.returnBook("The Lord of the Rings"); 
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Some advices about design of your code:

- You shouldn't make static your object's properties.
- You should override toString method of a class that you want to print with println.
- If you search in an array, you should get the founded index first and then you should do what you want.
- You should use equals method of a string object to compare content. == compares object's itself (reference) with another object, not content.
- Book object in the Library class is unnecessary. You already keep your books list in an ArrayList.